# I want the table section header index or section header title inside collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have implemented a collection view within a UITableViewCell. I want the table section header index or header title inside `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`

Here is my table view code:

```
extension ContentCatVCViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        print("table row index:: \(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection: Int) {
        if let headerTitle = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            headerTitle.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my table cell code:

```
extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:222/255, green:225/255, blue:227/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

        return cell
    }

}
```

How to get the `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` inside **`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`** function. Please help.

Comment: Why does the collection view cell need the table header index? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @rmaddy,... I want to show list like each category has different list dynamically..Just like App Store.

Comment: You need to pass cell-specific data to your `CategoryRow` cell in `cellRowAt`. You do not need to pass in an index.

Comment: I can't understand what u say..Can u explain

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAt method you are loading CollectionView. Means you are getting IndexPath where you are loading CollectionViews. So indexPath.section will be your header index for each CollectionView.